# jQuery promise execute sequential and followed by other statement block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to execute `if` statement after promise is completed. Even after using `$.when.apply(null, [promise goes here]).then()`; also does not work in sequential order. Where am I going wrong?

```
self.model.findGuests(expense.ExpNumber)
                .then(function (expReportGuests) {
                    return expReportGuests && expReportGuests.length > 0;
                });

        var hasItemizeOrGuests = this.options.selectedExpenses.some(expense => (expense.ItemizedLines && expense.ItemizedLines.length)
            || ($.Deferred().resolve(self.model.findGuests(expense.ExpNumber)
                .then(function (expReportGuests) {
                    return expReportGuests && expReportGuests.length > 0;
                }).promise())));

        if (hasItemizeOrGuests) {
            // do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`hasItemizeOrGuests` appears to be asynchronously set. By the time your code reaches the `if` statement, `hasItemizeOrGuests` is (probably!) still undefined. This could be why the statement isn't executing.

Comment: I want to use hasItemizeOrGuests for validation but the promise has to be executed to assign the boolean value to hasItemizeOrGuests variable. But the 'if' statement is executed later the promise is setting the value to hasItemizeOrGuests. how to make it work executed sequentially